# Python MQTT callbacks in OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, mqtt

I'm currently trying to use the paho mqtt library in Python3 in a object oriented context.
However, for some reason, the callback functions don't get called.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("IDS_LOGGER.refining")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class refiner(object):


def __init__(self,configpath="./sampleconfig.xml"):
    try:
        self.CONFIGPATH = configpath
        self.BROKER_IP = "localhost"

        self.parse_config()
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.connect(self.BROKER_IP)
        logging.info("Connected to {0}, starting MQTT loop".format(self.BROKER_IP))
        self.client.loop_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        print("error")


def on_message(self,client,userdata,msg):
    """MQTT Callback function for handling received messages"""
    print("message received!")


def on_connect(self,client,userdata,msg):
    print("connected!")
    self.client.subscribe("TRACED")
```

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `on_connect()` definition with:

```
def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("connected!")
        self.client.subscribe("TRACED")
```

Also for debugging purposes, consider printing the actual exception in the exception handler instead of just printing `"error"`:

```
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

With the fixes above, I tested your code by connecting to `test.mosquitto.org`:

```
class refiner(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.BROKER_IP = "test.mosquitto.org"
            self.client = mqtt.Client()
            self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
            self.client.connect(self.BROKER_IP, 1883, 60)
            logging.info("Connected to {0}, starting MQTT loop".format(self.BROKER_IP))
            self.client.loop_forever()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("connected!")
        self.client.subscribe("TRACED")

x = refiner()
```

And it successfully outputs:

```
INFO:root:Connected to test.mosquitto.org, starting MQTT loop
connected!
```

Answer (score 1):

I am Reading The Fine [Docs](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/).
They say you should:

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
....
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
```

Bbuuuttt, you didn't do that.
Within an OO class you have:

```
    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, msg):
```

Hmmm. Initially I thought that adding `self` was the problem, that your method would expect one more arg than paho provides when calling back.
But having written them both out, now I see that you turned `flags, rc` into `msg`, for reasons I cannot fathom.
I was thinking that somewhere behind the scenes paho might be logging a `takes 5 positional arguments but 4 were given` python error, but now it's unclear what happened.

In any event, you could finesse this detail and put the concern to rest with this code:

```
def on_connect(*args, **kwargs:
    with open('/tmp/log', 'a') as fout:
        fout.write('connected!\n')
```

I avoided `print()` just in case `sys.stdout` is no longer connected to your shell terminal.

Consider using `enable_logger` at DEBUG level, and perhaps even the `on_log` callback.

Comment: "for reasons I cannot fathom". Copy-paste victim, most definitely